# Literal Does Not Match 01861

Tags: sql, oracle, types

```
select case 
         when sale not in  TO_date(sale,'MMYY') then  'N' 
         else sale 
       end  test
  from daily sales
```

I would like to see if the data in the column meets the following criteria using the above select. I am receiving the following error:

> LITERAL DOES NOT MATCH FORMAT STRING

small data set

```
0109
0106
0409
```

column is  a `varchar`

Comment: Care to show the exact content of "sale" (for one row or a small number of rows)? Are they in the format 0316 (meaning March 2016), or something else? Is "sale" in varchar2 or similar character format, or in number format?

Comment: What is the data type forcolumn sale?

Comment: small data set0109
0106
0409

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `when sale not in  TO_date(sale,'MMYY')` anyways?  The condition doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @sstan - good point, I am looking just at to_date(...) and not noticing the surroundings! Maybe I should delete my answer...

Answer (score 0):

`to_date('0109', 'mmyy')` is correct, it will return 01-01-2009 00:00:00 AM (in one possible format). So the problem is likely in the column - you may have one or more value(s) that are not, in fact, four digits. You need to do some troubleshooting.

Something I would try:

`select max(length(sale)) as max_len, min(length(sale)) as min_len from table_name`

(`daily sales` cannot be a table name - table names don't have spaces in them)